# how to extract common lines across multiple file?

Tags: perl, shell, grep, comm

I have 15 different files that I want have a new file which include only common lines in all of them. for example:

```
File1:

id1
id2
id3

file2:

id2
id3
id4

file3:
id10
id2
id3

file4

id100
id45
id3
id2

I need the output be like:

newfile:

id2 
id3
```

I know this command works for each pair of files:

grep -w -f file1 file2 > output

but i need a command to works for more than 2 files.

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using grep

The same trick can be used more than once:

```
$ grep -w -f file1 file2 | grep -w -f file3 | grep -w -f file4
id2
id3
```

By the way, if you are looking for exact matches, not a *regular expression* matches, it is better and faster to use the `-F` flag:

```
$ grep -wFf file1 file2 | grep -wFf file3 | grep -wFf file4
id2
id3
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{nfiles++; delete fseen} !($0 in fseen){fseen[$0]++; seen[$0]++} END{for (key in seen) if (seen[key]==nfiles) print key}' file1 file2 file3 file4
id3
id2
```

- `FNR==1{nfiles++; delete fseen}`

  Every time that we start reading a new file, we do two things: (1) increment the file counter, `nfiles`. and (2) delete the array `fseen`.
- `!($0 in fseen){fseen[$0]; seen[$0]++}`

  If the current line is not a key in `fseen`, then add it to `fseen` and increment the count for this line in `seen`.
- `END{for (key in seen) if (seen[key]==nfiles) print key}`

  After we have read the last line of the last file, we look at every key in `seen`.  If the count for that key is equal to the number of files that we have read, `nfiles`, then we print that key.

Answer (score 6):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { $count = @ARGV }
           $h{$_}{$ARGV} = 1;
           }{
           print $_ for grep $count == keys %{ $h{$_} }, keys %h
           ' file* > newfile
```

- `-n` reads the input files line by line
- `-l` adds a newline to `print`
- the `@ARGV` array contains the input file names, assigning it to `$count` at the `BEGIN`ning just counts them
- `$ARGV` contains the name of the current input file
- `$_` contains the current line read from the file.
- the `%h` hash contains ids as keys, each key contains a hash reference with file names that contained the id as keys
- `}{` is the "Eskimo greeting" operator, it introduces code that runs once the input is exhausted
- we only output the ids whose number of files is equivalent to the number of all files. It works for any number of files.

Comment: Doesn't `-l` also make `chomp` superfluous?

Answer (score 1):

```
     grep -hxf file1 file2 file3 file4 |sort -u
     id2
     id3

     # For storing it to any file, 
     grep -hxf file1 file2 file3 file4 |sort -u > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The [zet](https://github.com/yarrow/zet) command provides set operations between input files. Use the `intersect` option to get common lines across all the input files. The input content doesn't have to be sorted. The output order will be same as the order of input lines.

```sh
$ zet intersect file1 file2 file3 file4
id2
id3
```

Here's some relevant details [from the notes section](https://github.com/yarrow/zet#notes):

- Each output line occurs only once, because we're treating the files as sets and the lines as their elements.
- Zet reads entire files into memory. Its memory usage is roughly proportional to the file size of its largest argument plus the size of the (eventual) output.